# CSS Border Radius Second Radius Explanation

Tags: css

I was reading the docs at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

The border radius attribute seems to have a second radius value,

```
/* The syntax of the second radius allows one to four values */
/* (first radius values) / radius */
border-radius: 10px 5% / 20px;

/* (first radius values) / top-left-and-bottom-right | top-right-and-bottom-left */
border-radius: 10px 5% / 20px 30px;

/* (first radius values) / top-left | top-right-and-bottom-left | bottom-right */
border-radius: 10px 5px 2em / 20px 25px 30%;

/* (first radius values) / top-left | top-right | bottom-right | bottom-left */
border-radius: 10px 5% / 20px 25em 30px 35em;
```

I am aware of the border radius attribute and it's short syntax but I don't understand what does the values after '/' do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first set of values defines the horizontal radius. The optional second set of values, preceded by a ‘/’ , defines the vertical radius. If only one set of values is supplied, it is used for both the vertical and horizontal radius.

Answer (score 2):

Complete form is something like this:

```
border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px / 50px 50px 50px 50px;
```

or we can write:

```
border-radius: top-left-up top-right-up bottom-right-down bottom-left-down /
               top-left-left top-right-right bottom-right-right bottom-left-left;
```

For example:

top-left-up: Curvature of upper side of top-left corner.

bottom-right-right: Curvature of right side of bottom-right corner.

Every corner can have different curvature not only from others but also in different sides of itself.

```css
.box {
 background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px / 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box2 {
 background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 50px / 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box3 {
 background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px / 10px 50px 50px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box, .box2, .box3 {display: inline-block}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

Comment: the "or we can write:" example makes this very easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

The values after / are the actual values of how round each corner of a rectangle is.

First value after / is a value that has to do with the **top-left** corner.
The second one is about **top-right**, the third about **bottom-right** and the last about **bottom-left**.

Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/NikolaosG/agevgutL/

A green box with a square that has each of its corners rounded to the corresponding amount in the values based on CSS rules.

```
.box {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px 5% / 50px 20px 30px 5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if the values after the / are the actual values, then what values are the ones before?

Comment: Those refer to the first radius values. The other refer to the final ones. If it's complicated for you, you can simply ignore that and use 4 values like you would do in margin or padding.

Comment: Sorry, I think my answer wasn't 100% comprehensive. When I say first I mean the following: https://jsfiddle.net/NikolaosG/agevgutL/1/